# AttributeError while doing two plots on a jupyter notebook cell

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm using seaborn and matplotlib to make plots, one is a box plot:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x=data["MEDV"])
```

The other one is an histogram at which I change the scale of the axis:

```
g = sns.distplot(data['MEDV'])  
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0))
```

Both plots works just fine if I made them on different cells, but if I use the same cell:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x=data["MEDV"])

g = sns.distplot(data['MEDV'])  
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0))
```

I get following error:

```
AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter.
```

Comment: The question lacks a full example, but I imagine the issue is that the boxplot puts textual tick labels on the plot, which can't be rendered in scientific notation (because they are not numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two subplots, each with one of the plots in it:

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
sns.boxplot(x=data, ax=ax)

sns.distplot(data, ax=ax2)  
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0))
```

[image]

If you want two different figures, one for each plot:

```
plt.figure()
sns.boxplot(x=data)

plt.figure()
sns.distplot(data)  
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0))
```

[image]